# Pass localStorage data from input

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Reformulated question: I'm trying to pass over the user name from the checkout page to the Order Finished page. User types in his name in a input field with id="v65-onepage-billfirstname". However, the next page isn't returning the information needed.

Working example I created: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G6A7P0HOVXD6

Also, I don't know why it doesn't work on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nandobtz/0yn6uqL3/10/

And here's what I have now on the website:

on checkout page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = document.getElementById('v65-onepage-billfirstname').value;
    localStorage.setItem("fname", x);
});
```

order finished page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = localStorage.getItem("fname");
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;
});
```

HTML:

```
<span id='result'></span>
```

I need to pass on the user's name so I can say something like: Thank you, David!

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that it's storing the name when the page first loads (and the name is thus empty), rather than when the user's finished typing in the name? If so, perhaps you could store it on a "Submit" button click instead, or similar.

Comment: It's possible, yes. Unfortunately the "submit" button is hardcoded (Volusion). :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the value when the page is ready. You need to set the value when  the input is updated or when your form is submitted.

You can make that easily like :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById("v65-onepage-billfirstname").addEventListener("input", function() {
    var x = this.value;
    localStorage.setItem("fname", x);
  });
});
```

Comment: It just worked, actually. Just needed to fix the closing of your code. })  }); Thanks a lot

Comment: To close it, you should use }) }); instead of }); });

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the name value on document load, at which point the input is empty. To verify you can try to `console.log(x)` in your set function. In order to properly set the value you'll need to save it on some action, probably when checkout has been completed. For that you can listen to `onSubmit` event from a form.